# how to make sankyplots with no color for source and target node and how to do legend to show the different colors of linkgroup

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets

I am working on network data and want to visualize it using `sankeyNetwork()` from the [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) package in [r](/questions/tagged/r).
In my data frame, I have a source node and a target node, value, and a grouping column group.

1. How can I make the sankey plot without coloring the nodes (both source and target with no color)?
2. I want to color the link lines by a variable group `LinkGroup = "group"` and I want to know how to make a legend to show that the different colors of the links are actually representing the group variable.

here is the code and the data frame...

```r
# Libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(networkD3)

# Load dataset from github

data <- read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/13_AdjacencyDirectedWeighted.csv", header=TRUE) %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  gather(key = "key", value = "value", -rowname) %>%
  filter(value > 0) %>% 
  rename(source = rowname,  target =key) %>%
  select("source", "target", "value") %>%
  mutate(group = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B",7), rep("C", 8), rep("D", 10)))
nodes <- data.frame(name=c(as.character(data$source), as.character(data$target)) %>% unique())

data$IDsource=match(data$source, nodes$name)-1 
data$IDtarget=match(data$target, nodes$name)-1

# Make the Network
sankeyNetwork(Links = data,
              Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "IDsource",
              Target = "IDtarget",
              Value = "value",
              NodeID = "name", 
              sinksRight=FALSE,
              nodeWidth=40,
              fontSize=13,
              nodePadding=20,
              LinkGroup = "group")
```

Comment: By “no color” you mean white?

Comment: Yes it can be....my aim is not to color the nodes  and color only the linker line based on group variable and giving legend for the linker lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue to let the link nodes be given automatically chosen colors based on their group, and effectively turn off coloring of the nodes with the `NodeGroup = NULL` option/argument

```r
sankeyNetwork(Links = data,
              Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "IDsource",
              Target = "IDtarget",
              Value = "value",
              NodeID = "name", 
              sinksRight=FALSE,
              nodeWidth=40,
              fontSize=13,
              nodePadding=20,
              LinkGroup = 'group',
              NodeGroup = NULL)
```

[image]

---

`networkD3` does not have any built-in legend creation options, however, if you want to make a legend yourself, you'll probably want to use a consistent set of colors so that you can use them with whatever you use to make a legend. You can do that like this...

```r
colourScale <- 
  'd3.scaleOrdinal()
     .domain(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
     .range(["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"])'

sankeyNetwork(Links = data,
              Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "IDsource",
              Target = "IDtarget",
              Value = "value",
              NodeID = "name", 
              sinksRight=FALSE,
              nodeWidth=40,
              fontSize=13,
              nodePadding=20,
              LinkGroup = 'group',
              NodeGroup = NULL,
              colourScale = colourScale)
```

[image]